# Execute custom code after command was executed

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have a TreeView control, and after a new node is added, I need to execute some custom code (ex expand the node, make it visible, and fire begind edit method). Since I want this to be available in every instance of TreeView control, I thought of subclassing the TreeView control.

Now, in order for treeview to know when the new node is added, it would either have an event that is fired when item is added (which it doesn't), or to have a reference to command that was executed to add a new item.

So two questions:

1) Is there a way to add an event in TreeView that would be fired whenever a treenode is added (I am always adding nodes through source collection from ViewModel) - I could not find any way to do this

2) I could add an AddCommand property to TreeList, that would be bound to ViewModel's AddCommand, and then have some button, or ContextMenu item that would bind to TreeList.AddCommand, instead of view model. This way TreeView would hold reference to AddCommand, but the drawback would be that actual usage would be kind of wierd. Question: How can I know when an TreeView's AddCommand (or any command, to that matter) is executed, so I can fire some custom code after it? It seems that CommandManager.AddExecutedHandler is a solution, but I am unable to execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this any help?

```
public class CustomTreeControl : TreeView
{
    ...

    // WPF only
    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);

        Debug.WriteLine("OnItemsSourceChanged");
    }

    // WPF + Silverlight
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);

        Debug.WriteLine("OnItemsChanged: {0}", e.Action);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it seems that this event is fired only when the whole collection bound to ItemsSource is changed, not when the item is added/removed.

Comment: @Phil is correct.

When a control's ItemsSource is bound to a collection it is notified when an element is added or removed by listening for the INotifyCollectionChanged event. The ObservableCollection raises this event when an element is added or removed which is why the View 'auto-magically' knows about the changes.

A TreeView handles these changes through the OnItemsChanged handler. When the collection raises the the INotifyCollectionChanged event the OnItemsChanged handler will be called.

Comment: That's correct.  When ItemsSource is initialized OnItemsChanged is called with e.Action = NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset.  There are enumerations for Add/Remove/Replace/Move/Reset.

Comment: I dont know why I was not informed by SO about these two comments. Anyway, you where right, if underlying collection implement INCC, it works as expected. My problem is that I tried it and it didnt raise this event, due to that this class was using List<T>. My bad, sorry.

Comment: Now I understand where was the problem. WHen there is a hierarchy collection, when you add a childitem to a treeview, this event is NOT fired, altough node is added to the treeview. However, when you add a root item, then it fires this event.